# How to use Spring's Resource Bundle in a custom library tag?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, autowired, resourcebundle

My Resource bundle is working fine with Controllers and Services etc, but somehow I can't access it within a custom tag.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:/spring/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

Here is a part of the tag:

```
@Component
public class FormSection extends BodyTagSupport {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

@Override
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {

    try {

    // messageSource causes a NULL POINTER here
    messageSource.getMessage("name", null, new Locale("us")));

    return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;

}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException; Autowire doenst work. I can see my class is being scanned.

I also tried using applicationContext by implementing ApplicationContextAware but doenst work:

```
messageSource = (ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource)applicationContext.getBean("messageSource");
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Tag instances are created by the container, not by Spring. They can't be Spring components and are thus not autowired.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I solved it by implementing ApplicationContextAware